# Getting higher speeds on µTorrent than what my ISP gives me

Tags: internet, download, utorrent

I have a 1Mbps down connection. After 10 GB of usage, speed comes down to 512Kbps, which is quite sluggish.

I was wondering, that is it possible to tweak µTorrent and find a torrent with appropriate number of seeders so that my speed goes above the current 64 KBps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have ***any*** control over the speed limit imposed by your ISP whatever software or hardware you use.

The **only** possible exception would be to ***illegally*** hack their system.  This is not necessarily possible and if it is, it must be extremely complex.